# How can I get ruby's JSON to follow object references like Pry/PP?

Tags: json, ruby, pry, rbvmomi

I've stared at this so long I'm going in circles...

I'm using the rbvmomi gem, and in Pry, when I display an object, it recurses down thru the structure showing me the nested objects - but to_json seems to "dig down" into some objects, but just dump the reference for others> Here's an example:

```
[24] pry(main)> g
=> [GuestNicInfo(
   connected: true,
   deviceConfigId: 4000,
   dynamicProperty: [],
   ipAddress: ["10.102.155.146"],
   ipConfig: NetIpConfigInfo(
     dynamicProperty: [],
     ipAddress: [NetIpConfigInfoIpAddress(
        dynamicProperty: [],
        ipAddress: "10.102.155.146",
        prefixLength: 20,
        state: "preferred"
      )]
   ),
   macAddress: "00:50:56:a0:56:9d",
   network: "F5_Real_VM_IPs"
 )]
[25] pry(main)> g.to_json
=> "[\"#<RbVmomi::VIM::GuestNicInfo:0x000000085ecc68>\"]"
```

Pry apparently just uses a souped-up pp, and while "pp g" gives me close to what I want, I'm kinda steering as hard as I can toward json so that I don't need a custom parser to load up and manipulate the results.

The question is - how can I get the json module to dig down like pp does? And if the answer is "you can't" - any other suggestions for achieving the goal? I'm not married to json - if I can get the data serialized and read it back later (without writing something to parse pp output... which may already exist and I should look for it), then it's all win.

My "real" goal here is to slurp up a bunch of info from our vsphere stuff via rbvmomi so that I can do some network/vm analysis on it, which is why I'd like to get it in a nice machine-parsed format. If I'm doing something stupid here and there's an easier way to go about this - lay it on me, I'm not proud. Thank you all for your time and attention.

Update: Based on Arnie's response, I added this monkeypatch to my script:

```
class RbVmomi::BasicTypes::DataObject
   def to_json(*args)
      h = self.props
      m = h.merge({ JSON.create_id => self.class.name })
      m.to_json(*args)
   end
end
```

and now my to_json recurses down nicely. I'll see about submitting this (or the def, really) to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.to_json` works in a recursive manner, the default behavior is [defined as](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON/Ext/Generator/GeneratorMethods/Object.html):

> Converts this object to a string (calling to_s), converts it to a JSON string, and returns the result. This is a fallback, if no special method to_json was defined for some object.

`json` library has added some implementation for some common classes (check the left hand side of [this documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html)), such as `Array`, `Range`, `DateTime`.

For an array, `to_json` first convert all the elements to json object, concat then together, and then add the array mark `[`/`]`.

For your case, you need to define your customized `to_json` method for `GuestNicInfo`, `NetIpConfigInfo` and `NetIpConfigInfoIpAddress`. I don't know your implementation about these three classes, so I wrote a example to demonstrate how to achieve this:

```
require 'json'

class MyClass
  attr_accessor :a, :b
  def initialize(a, b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end
end

data = [MyClass.new(1, "foobar")]
puts data.to_json
#=> ["#<MyClass:0x007fb6626c7260>"]    

class MyClass
  def to_json(*args)
    {
      JSON.create_id => self.class.name,
      :a => a,
      :b => b
    }.to_json(*args)
  end
end

puts data.to_json
#=> [{"json_class":"MyClass","a":1,"b":"foobar"}]
```

Comment: Good enough - I had hoped there was a magic flag or such that would let it handle this in the same manner as pp, but I gather pp has the same sort of requirements on objects (ie. they need a .pp or such of their own). This is enough that I can add this to the library and submit a patch to the upstream...

Comment: Just as a followup for people finding this later, I added the following monkey-patch to my code:

   `class RbVmomi::BasicTypes::DataObject
      def to_json(*args)
         h = self.props
         m = h.merge({ JSON.create_id => self.class.name })
         m.to_json(*args)
      end
   end`

and now my to_json recurses down nicely. I'll see about submitting this (or the def, really) to the project.